# Euler Characteristic of Side identification

Tags: general-topology, geometry, geometric-topology

Let $S$ be a surface obtained by identifying the sides of a regular hexagon in pairs.

I want to show $\chi(S) > -1 $.

I can see how we can obtain surfaces with $\chi(S) = 0,1,2$ but I think I'm missing something for this inequality.

We start of with 6 vertices, 6 edges, 1 face. Whenever I identify a pair of edges it seems to "remove" edges and vertices but I haven't made this into an argument.

Comment: First, have you counted how many faces and edges can occur **after** the sides are identified in pairs? And then the same question for vertices?

Comment: i might be being stupid here, but what happens if we use the identification aabbcc?

doesn't that leave 1 face, 3 edges, 1 vertex?

Comment: That should have four vertices, not one. (It glues to a sphere.)

Comment: ok this is what is confusing me, i don't really see that, i must be confused. To me it seems each of the adjacent vertices of the hexagon will be identified